# Overwrite registeredName

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I've a method that when called returns a `LinearGradientBrush` with random color for the `GradientStop` and I use on them `mylabel.RegisterName` for later use in a `storyboard` animation.
To prevent the error on first call where no registered name are present I do this:

```
try
{
    myLabel.UnregisterName("GS1");
    myLabel.UnregisterName("GS2");
    myLabel.UnregisterName("GS3");
    myLabel.UnregisterName("GS4");
}
catch
{
}
```

I have not found a way to overwrite registered name. There's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>What about `UnregisterName`?</strike>

(*That's what I get for attempting to answer when I can only read part of the question...*)

Digging around a bit more, may have found another (WAY simpler) alternative:

```
var isGs1Defined = NameScope.GetNameScope(myLabel).FindName("GS1") == null;
```

or packaged up nicely:

```
public static bool IsNameRegistered(DependencyObject depObject, string name)
{
    var namescope = NameScope.GetNameScope(depObject);
    if(namescope == null)
        return false;
    return namescope.FindName(name) != null;
}
```

Comment: Hah - evidently not; apologies, when I read these on my phone, bits get cut off in my mobile view. Will revisit when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @Christian sorry 'bout that, revised the answer

Comment: +1 for your time and for a nice alternative.I like it much more than the `try catch` to avoid an obvious exception. I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: No worries - FWIF, you'd want a null check between GetNameScope and FindName; it *can* return null.

Comment: what's `DependencyObject do` is  never used?